# Concatenate FASTQ files from 2 folders with the same structure

Tags: bash, fastq

I am trying to concatenate FASTQ files that the same files in 2 different folders.

E.g.

```
Folder_A/Sample_10_DNA
```

contains

```
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz,
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz,
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz,
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

and

```
Folder_B/Sample_10_DNA
```

contains

```
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
Sample_10_DNA_S7_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

I have about 20 of these folders and am thinking of using the cat function to concatenate the FASTQ files using a BASH script. E.g.

```
cat Folder_A/Sample_10_DNA/Sample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz Folder_B/Sample_10/DNA_Sample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz >Folder_C/Sample_10_DNA/ample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

Would appreciate any advice I can get. :)

Tried a Bash script but did not have the expertise to build it.

Comment: Do you really have folders named `Folder_A, Folder_B` etc? And are there really the same filenames in all folders? Eliminate a whole class of problems/errors in your future work by resisting the temptation in use space chars in the filenames and directories. Doesn't `Sample_10_DNAContainsSample_10_DNA_S7_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz` work just as well (-;?

Comment: your idea to use `cat DirA/file DirB/file ... DirZ/file > Combined/file` is a good idea and should be efficient. Note however that you can't `cat` `.gz` files together with out first using `gunzip` on them. But there are tricks to keep that simple too. Without answers to my questions above, I am very reluctant to spend furrther time on your problem. Did you figure this yourself? If so, then post your answer and you can accept your own answer after 48 hrs, and gain valuable reputation points here. ....

Comment: If you haven't solved this, then I have a general idea on how to proceed with the real substance of your problem, but I don't want to post an answer, and then have you come back and say "Oh, one more thing I forgot to tell you" and spend more time on a completely different problem. Finally, as you haven't accepted an answer, upvoted an answer, or left a comment on those aanswers, I'm even less inclined to spend time on this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along the lines of this `for` loop:

```
for filename in Folder_A/Sample_10_DNA/* ; do  
  base=$(basename $f)
  cat $filename Folder_B/Sample_10/$base > Folder_C/Sample_10_DNA/$base
done
```

Besides the for loop, the other key piece is the use of the `basename` command to get just the filename without the directory. You can collapse things to a 1-liner like this:

```
for filename in Folder_A/Sample_10_DNA/* ; do base=$(basename $f) ; cat $filename Folder_B/Sample_10/$base > Folder_C/Sample_10_DNA/$base ; done
```